# Header/ Footer nav update jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2007

I created a header and footer navigation with different states using jQuery. I'm having an issue updating the header nav when the footer nav is clicked. For example when the user clicks list 1 in the footer nav I will like for the header nav to update as well to same selection. I included a jsfiddle example of what I'm doing.

Update: The header nav have the main list items, and the footer nav has the main list items along with sub navs. I want to achieve the same functionality but instead when the first list item labeled footerTitle is clicked it updates to header nav as well. I updated the jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/WkZuv/40/

```
$(".Nav > li").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");
    }
});

$(".footer > li").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(".Nav > li").addClass("menuClicked");     

         $(".footer > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");  
    }
});


.menuHover{
    background-color:#666;
    color:#fff;
}
.menuClicked{
    background-color:yellow;
    color:#666;
}

<h1>Header NAV</h1>
<ul class="Nav">
    <li class ="menuClicked"> List 1 </li> 
    <li>List 2 </li>
    <li> List 3 </li>
    <li> List 4 </li>
    <li> List 5</li>
</ul>

<hr />



<h1>FOOTER NAV</h1>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 1 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 2 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 3 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 4 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
<ul class="footer">
    <li class ="footerTitle"> List 5 </li> 
    <li>Sub List 2 </li>
    <li>Sub List 3 </li>
    <li> Sub List 4 </li>
    <li>Sub List 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://jsfiddle.net/WkZuv/28/

You should also think about caching your jquery objects.

```
$(".Nav > li").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");
    } });

$(".footer > li").live({
    mouseover:function(){
        $(this).addClass("menuHover");
    },
    mouseout:function(){
        $(this).removeClass("menuHover");
    },
    click:function(){
        $(".Nav > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(".Nav > li").eq($(this).index()).addClass("menuClicked");     

         $(".footer > li").removeClass("menuClicked");
        $(this).addClass("menuClicked");  
    } });
```

Comment: thanks! I'm using jquery 1.5.2 does .eq work in there as well?